# WebMock: undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass after using `stub_request`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, amazon-s3, carrierwave, webmock

My app is using Carrierwave + Fog for storing images on Amazon S3. I have an Rspec feature test for the registration process that uses Capybara's `attach_file` helper to add the file. The spec looks like this:

```
feature 'Registration' do
  before do
    stub_request(:any, /amazonaws/)
  end

  scenario 'New business signs up' do
    visit new_user_registration_path
    fill_in 'Name',         with: 'my business'
    attach_file 'Logo',     with: "#{Rails.root}/tmp/image.png"
    click_button 'Sign up'

    expect(page).to have_text("Business successfully created.")
  end
end
```

The stub seems to be working correctly but the test is failing because of an error in the controller:

```
  1) Registration 
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Create Business'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb:36:in `create_with_user'
     # ./spec/features/registration/signup_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is what the controller looks like:

```
  def create_with_user
    @business = Business.new(business_params)
    if @business.save
      redirect_to business_url(@business), success: 'Business was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new_with_user
    end
  end
```

Line 36 is the line where `if @business.save` is called. Using `binding.pry`, I've noticed that the `logo` attribute on `@business` is `nil` after it is instantiated in line 35 and I'm guessing this has to do with the stubbed request to AWS not returning whatever CarrierWave needs to assign the attribute. I'm not sure how to solve this so that the test passes, though. Thanks in advance for any help!